# How to insert a blank space between every consecutive character

Tags: python, whitespace

I'm using python 3.4.

I need to be able to insert a blank space in a string anywhere there are two consecutive characters (counting spaces as a character as well) and have it output it without having white space at the beginning or end, unless the input string begins or ends with a space.

```
def emphasize(s):
    s = s.replace('',' ')
return s
```

This is what I have so far, but it returns with spaces at the beginning and end.

For example, if the string ('very important') is the input, it should return:

```
v e r y   i m p o r t a n t
```

but my function returns (there is an extra space at the start and end):

```
 v e r y   i m p o r t a n t
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why my code does not work, and suggest something that will work better?

Comment: Most langues come with a trimming function which removes leading and trailing characters, commonly whitespace.

Comment: adding the programming language you're using as a tag would certainly help.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention which language.

Answer (score 3):

for Python, use:

```
s = s.replace('',' ').strip()
```

> **str.strip([chars])**
>
> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed.

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

By default, it strips whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

`join` is more clean, and then optionally `strip()` the end result:

```
s = 'some string is cool  '
' '.join(s).strip()  # .strip() removes leading & trailing spaces
print(s)
```

> `'s o m e  s t r i n g  i s  c o o l'`

Comment: I didn't upvote you at first, thinking `join` was a strange solution because `s` isn't a list of elements, so how does it make sense to join them back together? Sometime overnight, it clicked, and join over an iterable *is* a clean way to put spaces between characters, and not add any at the start and end. Neat.

Comment: Yeah, I think your answer better nails the crux of the question, but when I first read my immediate reaction was to immediately avoid using `replace()`, which feels not pythonic. But I guess it's important to stick to the example code... we never know what else is going on.